# Exception on ServletFileUpload

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

**Situation** : I'm uploading a file with a few thousand records. Upto file sizes of 100 kB, there's no problem. However, I get an exception at file sizes of over 100 kB.

**Problem**: I get an exception at the following line:

```
List<DiskFileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

The exception I get is:

```
Error while processing multipart request:org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\DNDUtility\upload_tmp\upload_172408d6_14c27eae211__8000_00000001.tmp (The system cannot find the path specified) : Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\DNDUtility\upload_tmp\upload_172408d6_14c27eae211__8000_00000001.tmp (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I've even set the ServletUpload.MaxFileSize() to 1 MB. Yet, I get an exception if I try to upload files over 100 kB.

Comment: Please provide more details on this like your configuration parameters, servlet version, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (setting it to 3MB):

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory(3000 * 1024, tmpDir));
```

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your answer. How do you know OP has a package called `net.jforum.context.web` and that there's a `WebRequestContext` class inside that package?

Comment: Sorry, he is not using JBoss apparently :D

Comment: I have worked with JBoss and that text (now removed) is not involved either. Anyway, I still don't know if this may solve OP's issue.

Comment: Ok, it was just a suggestion which may or may not work.. You can offer an alternative

Comment: adrCoder, thank you. Your solution worked. Also for the record, I was running Apache 7.x, and JDK 1.7.